# Count the number of transactions in sql

Tags: sql, vb6

```
ORNumber     Fixeds     Savings
-------------------------------
1111111111   2500.00    3000.00
2222222222   2000.00    3000.00
1111111112   2500.00    3000.00
2222222221   2000.00    3000.00
```

What is the correct sql statement to come up with this kind of output. Just like the passbook reporting...thanks in advance.

```
Counter      ORNumber     Fixeds    Savings
--------------------------------------------
1            1111111111   2500.00   3000.00
2            2222222222   2000.00   3000.00
3            1111111112   2500.00   3000.00
4            2222222221   2000.00   3000.00
```

Comment: So you want to add a row number in a select query? what database? what *order* defines the row number?

Comment: What does "Counter" represent? You need to be more specific.

Comment: Counter represent as the number of transaction. Counter is not included in my real table, its only virtual column.

Comment: "SET @x=0; SELECT @x:=@x+1 AS Counter,ORNumber,Fixeds,Savings FROM contribution" i use this statement and it works fine but when i use this in recordset like this: SET RS=CN.Execute(""SET @x=0; SELECT @x:=@x+1 AS Counter,ORNumber,Fixeds,Savings FROM contribution") but i encounter an error.

Comment: What error? In that statement @x is not declared. You are also not providing an ORDER BY, without one the order of rows is *not* guaranteed at all.

Comment: Set RS = CN.Execute("DECLARE @x int; SET @x=0; SELECT @x:=@x+1 AS Counter,ORNumber,Fixeds,Savings FROM contribution")
Set DataReport1.DataSource = RS
DataReport1.Show 'This is my code but it display the error like this: "You have an error in your SQL syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your MYSQL Server"

Comment: I tried this code and it works. Set RS = CN.Execute("SELECT @x:=@x+1 AS Counter,ORNumber,Fixeds,Savings FROM Contribution")

Comment: Updated version. Because my first example the value in @x is static.                                               Set RS = CN.Execute("SET @x=0")
    Set RS = CN.Execute("SELECT @x:=@x+1 AS Counter,ORNumber,Fixeds,Savings FROM contribution")
    Set DataReport1.DataSource = RS
    DataReport1.Show vbModal

Answer (score 0):

Use [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) for counter column

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() over(order by [NameOfYouColumnThatIdentifiesARow]) as [Counter] , 
ORNumber, Fixeds, Savings from [YourTable]
```

Comment: Counter column is not included in my table, it is only a virtual column.

Comment: Row_number() just produces the counter value, but you have to specify a "real" column so that the counter values are ordered correctly (as if you would add a order by xxx after the FROM clause)

Comment: "SET @x=0; SELECT @x:=@x+1 AS Counter,ORNumber,Fixeds,Savings FROM contribution" i use this statement and it works fine but when i use this in recordset like this: SET RS=CN.Execute(""SET @x=0; SELECT @x:=@x+1 AS Counter,ORNumber,Fixeds,Savings FROM contribution") but i encounter an error.

Comment: You are not declaring the @x variable in your 2.nd statement:
SET RS=CN.Execute(""DECLARE @x int; SET @x=0; SELECT @x:=@x+1 AS Counter,ORNumber,Fixeds,Savings FROM contribution")
The way you are executing your query does not garantee the order of the records -> if you have something to use for ordering the result, this would be the column that is missing in my example

Comment: Set RS = CN.Execute("DECLARE @x int; SET @x=0; SELECT @x:=@x+1 AS Counter,ORNumber,Fixeds,Savings FROM contribution")
Set DataReport1.DataSource = RS
DataReport1.Show 'This is my code but it display the error like this: "You have an error in your SQL syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your MYSQL Server"

Comment: I tried this code and it works. Set RS = CN.Execute("SELECT @x:=@x+1 AS Counter,ORNumber,Fixeds,Savings FROM Contribution")

Answer (score 0):

try this...
In SQL Server 2005+:

```
SELECT  m.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column) AS rn
FROM    mytable m
```